# C : Passing bi-dimensional array of pointers as argument

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I'm using a 2d-Array of pointers, each pointer points to a linked list of products.
I want to build a function that list all the products in all the lists.
This is my structure:

```
typedef struct object product, *pprod;
struct object{
int type;
int quantity;
pprod next;
};
```

This is how I'm defining the array (it has to be dynamic):

```
n=4;
m=3;
pprod (*t)[m] = malloc(n * sizeof *t);
list_all(t,n,m);
```

This is the function to show all the products:

```
void list_all(pprod** t , int size_n , int size_m) {
int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<size_n;i++){
        printf("--- Corridor ---: %d\n", i);
        for(j=0;j<size_m;j++){
            printf("--- Shelf ---: %d\n",j);
            printf("product:%d quantity:%d",t[i][j]->type,t[i][j]->quantity);
            }
     }
}
```

I'm having troubles passing the array as a parameter. Can you help me find the problem?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `pprod next` for if you have fixed quantity?

Comment: post your whole code if possible

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to have dynamically allocated array of products and you want to manipulate with them. Am I right?

Comment: Do you initialize the `malloc`ed memory for `t` at all?  And `t` is a pointer to an array.  Did you want an array of pointers instead?

Comment: In this case, I have 4 corridors, each corridor with 3 shelfs. Inside each shelf I need a list of products. I use pprod next to get the next element in the list.

Comment: Uh. What about having 3D array?

Comment: yes aschepler, I want an array of pointers.

Comment: array definition error : invalid conversion!

Comment: You want to represent x corridors * y shelfs * z products. For that you need a 3D array, not a 2D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first the creation of the array is wrong.  You are just assigning one (single) vector of size 4 to the m+1 th element (the t vector, unless you do it elsewhere, points to random-land).

```
n=4;
m=3;
product **t, *newitem;

t= (product **)calloc(n, sizeof(product *));  // array of n pointers (corridor)
for (int i= 0; i<n; i++) {
    t[i]= (product *)calloc(m, sizeof(product))  // array of m prod structs (m shelfs per corridor)
}
// access some array members (t[n][m] max t[0-2][0-3])
t[0][0].type= 0;
t[0][0].quantity= 0;
t[0][1].type= 1;
t[0][1].quantity= 11;
...
t[1][2].type= 12;
t[1][2].quantity= 1212;
....
t[2][3].type= 23;
t[2][3].quantity= 2323;

// more products could be linked to the existing ones
newitem= calloc(1, sizeof product);
newitem->type= 231;
newitem->quantity= 231231;
t[2][3].next= newitem;

// now list them via below function
list_all(t,n,m);
....


void list_all(product **t , int size_n , int size_m) 
{
    int i,j;
    product *p;

    for(i=0;i<size_n;i++){
        printf("--- Corridor ---: %d\n", i);
        for(j=0;j<size_m;j++){
            printf("--- Shelf ---: %d\n",j);
            p= &t[i][j]; 
            do { 
                 printf("product:%d quantity:%d", p->type, p->quantity);
                 p= p->next;
            } (while p!=NULL);
        }
     }
}
```

See also my comment at Etienne's answer for more details.

Comment: This task is deep in the wonderland of pointerland.  Creating bi-dimensional things of dynamic size in native C is always some sort of cludge.  (Btw, what you are creating in your has nothing to do with a linked list ... linked lists are an entirely different type of beast.)

Comment: Your code it's working but only considering 1 product by shelf

Comment: Casting the return type of malloc is required in C++, but not in C.

Comment: You declared `pprod **t;`, so t is of type `prod***`, I think you meant `prod **t`.

Comment: But now you call `list_all` with a `prod**` as first argument whereas it takes a prod***. The OP needs a 3D array but is using a 2D array.

Comment: Making a last change to this, for a whimsical attempt to use something akin to a linked list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It's working as intended.
Can you just tell me one last thing, how do I pass one array element as parameter? Im trying to build a function that adds a product in one shelf, here's the code: 
http://pastebin.com/TQUiLwyx

Answer (score 1):

From your problem description you want to represent i corridors * j shelfs * k products, where each product has a quantity and a type.

In your question you said you want to use a 2D array of pointers but your function `list_all` takes a 3D array as first argument (`t` is of type `object***`). Furthermore your structure `object` is meant to be a linked list node since it has a `next` member, but you use it like an array, for example with `t[i][j]->quantity`, which can not work and attempts to access unallocated memory.

To help reducing this kind of confusion name your variable more explicitly and avoid one letter variable names (n,m,t in your problem) except for loop iterators. Your program will be easier to read and those problems will appear more easily.

Here is a working solution to your problem using a 3D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct object prod;

struct object {
int type;
int quantity;
};

void list_all(prod ***shop, int nb_corridors , int nb_shelfs, int nb_prods) 
{
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = 0; i < nb_corridors; i++) {
        printf ("--- Corridor ---: %d\n", i);
        for (j = 0; j < nb_shelfs; j++) {
            printf ("--- Shelf ---: %d\n", j);
            for (k = 0; k < nb_prods; k++) {
                printf ("--- Product ---: %d\n", k);
                printf ("type:%d quantity:%d\n", 
                        shop[i][j][k].type, shop[i][j][k].quantity);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int nb_corridors = 4;
    int nb_shelfs = 5;
    int nb_prods = 3;
    prod ***shop;

    // array of n pointers (corridor)
    shop = malloc(nb_corridors * sizeof(*shop)); 
    printf("sizeof(*shop)=%ld\n", sizeof(*shop));

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < nb_corridors; i++) {
         // nb_shelfs shelfs per corridor)
        shop[i] = malloc(nb_shelfs * sizeof(*shop[i]));     
        printf("sizeof(*shop[i])=%ld\n", sizeof(*shop[i]));
        for(j = 0; j < nb_shelfs; j++) {
            shop[i][j] = malloc(nb_prods * sizeof(*shop[i][j]));
            printf("sizeof(*shop[i][j])=%ld\n", sizeof(*shop[i][j]));
        }
    }

    //initialize with dummy values
    int k;
    for(i = 0; i < nb_corridors; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < nb_shelfs; j++) {
            for(k = 0; k < nb_prods; k++) {
                shop[i][j][k].type = k;
                shop[i][j][k].quantity;
            }
        }
    }

    list_all(shop, nb_corridors, nb_shelfs, nb_prods);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for making a full working program (unlike myself, who just tried to fix it in the edit window).  But to be honest, I think this whole question is beyond repair (not your fault though), because, quite likely the inner loop (products) is meant to be a linked list as in: for(p= &shop[i][j]; p->next!=NULL; p= p->next) { printf("...", p->...); }

Comment: You're right, the representation of the problem is not clear :/

Answer (score 0):

pprod is already a pointer, I believe the problem is how you pass the parameters to the function.

try changing to this function prototype:
t is already a pointer to a pointer and you aren't changing it anyhow..

```
void list_all(pprod* t , int size_n , int size_m) {
```

Comment: "Incompatible pointer types passing 'pprod(*)[m]' to parameter of type 'pprod *' ( aka 'struct object **')

Maybe I have an error on the Malloc instruction? What I need is a 2d-array of pointers to struct.